# Single Domain, Multiple Directories to host, NGINX Ubuntu instance

Tags: nginx

## Scenario

One domain hosted on mydomain.com

Root is
/var/www/mydomain/wordpress which points to mydomain.com

Would like to have path of:
/var/www/site2/wordpress point to mydomain.com/site2

And so on and forth for other directories I build in /var/www/ (i.e. /var/www/site3, site4 etc to mydomain.com/site3,site4)

### Sites Enabled File

Below is my config file in /etc/nginx/sites-available

```
server {

        root /var/www/mydomain/wordpress;
        index index.php;

        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

        location / {
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

location /site2 {
    root /var/www/site2/wordpress;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;   
}


location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

I have tried adjusting the /location of site2 to use both alias and root, and removing the $uri, but I either get a 404, or it re-directs me to the /var/www/mydomain/wordpress repository's wordpress 404 page not found. It seems there may be a redirect occurring, that I am not aware of.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will need to use `alias` in this scenario, but you also need nested `location` blocks to handle PHP requests for each WordPress instance. What are the contents of the `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` file?

Comment: You need to also make sure WordPress has proper site URL set in its settings.